# When doing a POST request on a model from a form it doesn't assign an ID to the object

Tags: python, django

When I add a post from admin it assigns the ID and I can link to the post. I get no errors when I go to that address. But if I create a post form it doesn't seem like I am getting an ID. I get an error that says there is no matching query. I thought the ID was automatically assigned.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/reports/5/this-is-even-more-formal/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'TheFishNetwork',
 'accounts',
 'subnetwork',
 'posts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/swapnil/PycharmProjects/fishnetwork/posts/views.py" in report_detail
  38.     user = User.objects.get(id=pk)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/swapnil/python_envs/fishenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /reports/5/this-is-even-more-formal/
Exception Value: User matching query does not exist.
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_report(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body']:
            report = FishingReport()
            report.title = request.POST['title']
            report.slug = slugify(report.title)
            report.body = request.POST['body']
            report.sub_network = SubNetwork.objects.get(sub_name=request.POST['sub'])
            report.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            report.author = request.user
            report.save()
            return render(request, 'posts/createreport.html')
    else:
        subnetwork = SubNetwork.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'posts/createreport.html',
                      {'subnetwork': subnetwork})


def report_detail(request, pk):
    report = FishingReport.objects.get(id=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(parent_report=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'posts/report_detail.html',
                  {'report': report,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'user': user})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/', views.create_report, name='create_report'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/([-\w]+)/$', views.report_detail, name='report_detail'),
]
```

models.py

```
class FishingReport(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    sub_network = models.ForeignKey(SubNetwork)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:report_detail',
                       args=[self.id,
                             self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Stack trace indicates its problem with `report_detail` view, so you need to show us that too.

Comment: You need to validate the form first before saving it.

Comment: added report_detail view

Comment: The logs clearly show the problem is on this line: `user = User.objects.get(id=pk)` with the message: `User matching query does not exist.`. so I guess the user ID in the URL is mismatch.

Comment: But it's not a mismatch as far as I can tell. I can get into the shell and get an object with the same ID and slug that is provided in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same primary key for accessing `Report` and the `User`:

```
report = FishingReport.objects.get(id=pk)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(parent_report=pk)
user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
```

In the URL, `pk=5` seems to be the ID of the report you have created and not of the User you are trying to access. And, looking at the stacktrace it seems that there is no user with id `5` in the database.

Comment: Yep. I was up to late last night. That was absolutely the issue. Thank you so much.